# Proof of Matrix Norm (Inverse Matrix)

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, inverse

Show for any induced matrix norm and nonsingular matrix A that
$$
\left\|A^{-1}\right\| ≥ (\left\|A\right\|)^{-1}
$$
where
$$
\left\|A^{-1}\right\| = \max_{\left\|x\right\|=1}\{\left\|A^{-1}x\right\|\}\\
\left\|A\right\| = \max_{\left\|x\right\|=1}\{\left\|Ax\right\|\}.
$$

I am not sure how to show that:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\left\|A^{-1}\right\| ≥ (\left\|A\right\|)^{-1}\\
\text{or}\\
\max_{\left\|x\right\|=1}\{\left\|A^{-1}x\right\|\} ≥ (\max_{\left\|x\right\|=1}\{\left\|Ax\right\|\})^{-1}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Comment: i am still learning how to write equations in here, is there a faster way? Ill put what Ive tried in the actual question portion, it doesn't seem to be working here

Comment: Please don't vote this question down, I am still learning how to use the special text. Thanks.

Comment: @ Megan: welcome to MSE!

Comment: Thanks! I used to use stack exchange all the time for coding, so excited to discover the math stack exchange. :)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use $\lVert AB\rVert \leq \lVert A\rVert \lVert B\rVert$, as the induced norm is in particular [submultiplicative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Definition). So that $\lVert I_n\rVert \leq \lVert A\rVert \lVert A^{-1}\rVert$.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose $|y|=1$ is such that $|A|=|Ay|$. Then $x=Ay/|A|$ also has norm $1$ so it follows that
$$
|A^{-1}|\geq |A^{-1}x|=|A^{-1}Ay/|A||=\frac{|y|}{|A|}=\frac{1}{|A|}=|A|^{-1}.
$$

Answer (score -1):

Proof:
$$
\left\|A^{-1}\right\| ≥ (\left\|A\right\|)^{-1}
$$
where
$$
\left\|A^{-1}\right\| = \max_{\left\|x\right\|=1}\{\left\|A^{-1}x\right\|\}\\
\left\|A\right\| = \max_{\left\|x\right\|=1}\{\left\|Ax\right\|\}\\
\left\|A\right\|^{-1} = (\max_{\left\|x\right\|=1}\{\left\|Ax\right\|\})^{-1} = (\min_{\left\|x\right\|=1}\{\left\|A^{-1}x\right\|\})
$$
and 
$$
\max_{\left\|x\right\|=1}\{\left\|A^{-1}x\right\|\} ≥(\min_{\left\|x\right\|=1}\{\left\|A^{-1}x\right\|\})
$$
therefore:
$$
\left\|A^{-1}\right\| ≥ (\left\|A\right\|)^{-1}
$$

Comment: Are you supposing here that $\min_{\left\|x\right\|=1}\{\left\|A^{-1}x\right\|\} = \|A\|^{-1}$?  That's a very interesting supposition, and you should probably prove that as a part of your proof