# How do I find the norm of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normed-spaces

I have the following matrix below and I would like to find the norm of the matrix. I learned that the norm of a matrix is the square root of the maximum eigenvalue multiplied by the transpose of the matrix times the matrix. Can anybody explain to me in further detail what steps I need to do after finding the maximum eigenvalue of the matrix below?

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        1 & 3 \\
        0 & 1 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there are several different [matrix norms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm), but the one often noted with a subscript 2 is what you describe, though your description is a bit hard to follow and perhaps you misunderstood something so let us start from the start.

Given a matrix $A$ you need to:

- compute $A^T A$ (I assume the matrix is real, for complex it is $A^{\ast}$ instead).
- compute the maximal eigenvalue $\lambda_{\max}$ of $A^T A$ (note all the eigenvalues are real and nonnegative), *not* of $A$.
- compute $\sqrt{\lambda_{\max}}$

Done. This is $||A||_2$.

Comment: This makes more sense! Thank you! I found many norms when researching online and I was not sure myself which one I was describing.

Comment: The wikipedia page [Matrix norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm) is quite good for he basic definitions.

Comment: On another note, how is the inverse norm of the matrix related to the norm of the matrix?

Comment: One has $||A^{-1}|| \ge ||A||^{-1} $ see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/943748/proof-of-matrix-norm-inverse-matrix for details.

Answer (score 3):

Multiplying by the transpose of the matrix gives
$$ A^TA = \begin{bmatrix}1&3\\3&10\end{bmatrix}$$
The eigenvalues of this matrix are found from the characteristic equation $\det(\lambda I - A^TA) = (\lambda-1)(\lambda-10)-9 = 0$. Solving this gives $\lambda^2-11\lambda+1=0$, or $\lambda = \frac{11\pm\sqrt{117}}{2}$.
The norm is the square root of the larger eigenvalue:
$$ \sqrt{\frac{11+\sqrt{117}}{2}} $$

Comment: Thank you! This makes more sense now.