# Induced norm of an inverse vs. inverse of an induced norm

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, linear-transformations

Let $A$ be an invertible matrix.  Are there any relationships between  $\| A \|^{-1}$ and $\| A^{-1}\|$,  where the induced norm is defined as
\begin{align}
\| B \| =\sup_{\| x \|\ \neq 0} \frac{ \| B x\|}{ \|x\|}\
\end{align}

For example, can we bound one with an another?

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/943748/proof-of-matrix-norm-inverse-matrix).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can.

I start with the following equality:
$$||B B^{-1}||=||I||=1$$
We know that for any norm the following property holds for arbitrary matrices $X$ and $Y$:
$$||XY|| \leq ||X||||Y||$$
If we select $X=B$ and $Y=B^{-1}$, the above inequality will result:
$$1 \leq ||B||||B^{-1}||$$
Another property of the norms is that they are always equal or greater than zero. Therefore, the above inequality will result in:
$$||B||^{-1} \leq ||B^{-1}||$$