# Why $\|(A + cI)^{-1}x\|\leq \frac{\|x\|}{\lambda_{\min}(A)}$

Tags: matrices, inequality, normed-spaces, inverse, upper-lower-bounds

Given $A\succ 0$ (positive-definite) and $c>0$, I am trying to show

$$\|(A + cI)^{-1}x\|\leq \frac{\|x\|}{\lambda_{\min}(A)} \tag{1}$$

using information like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/943748/proof-of-matrix-norm-inverse-matrix/943774) but without success so far. Could you please help to prove it? Any help is welcome.

**EDIT:** This inequality is an abstract form of the inequality

$$\left\| \left[f''(x_k) - r_M(x_k)\frac{M}{2}I \right]^{-1}f'(x_k)\right\| \leq \frac{\|f'(x_k)\|}{\lambda_{min}\left(f''(x_k)\right)}\tag{2}$$ appeared [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10107-006-0706-8) (Theorem 3). Here is the part of the proof

> [image]

Comment: Your title question is different from the question in the body, please clarify

Comment: You may first try the case where $A$ is a diagonal matrix.

Comment: @Thanks for the interest, I have made some clarifications. I hope I will get some feedback.

Comment: What do you mean by $A >0$?

Comment: @D_S positive-definite matrix. I did some edit.

Comment: It's not $\lambda_{\max}$, it is $\lambda_{\min}$.

Comment: @V.S.e.H. thanks, my mistake, I did the appropriate changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $A\succ 0$, so is $A+cI\succ 0$, so $\lVert (A+cI)^{-1}\rVert = \lambda_{\min}(A + cI)^{-1}$, and
$$
\lVert (A+cI)^{-1}x\rVert\leq \lVert (A+cI)^{-1}\rVert\lVert x\rVert = \frac{\lVert x\rVert}{\lambda_{\min}(A+cI)}\leq \frac{\lVert x\rVert}{\lambda_{\min}(A)}.
$$

Comment: May I ask you for a reference / proof for the $|| \dots || = \lambda_{min}$ equality?

Comment: @user7427029 Sure! Note that for a symmetric matrix $A$, $\lVert A \rVert =\lvert\lambda_{\max}\rvert$. Also, if $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, positive definite, then $1/\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A^{-1}$. But then $\lambda_{\max}(A^{-1}) = \lambda_{\min}(A)^{-1}$, since $0<\lambda_{\min} \leq \lambda_{\max}$, so $\lVert A^{-1}\rVert = \lambda_{\min}(A)^{-1}.$ If you want that included in the answer let me know.

Comment: Well done, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. E.g. when $c>0$ is small, $A=\operatorname{diag}(1,c)$ and $x=(0,1)^T$, we have
$$
\|(A+cI)^{-1}x\|=\frac{1}{2c}>1=\frac{\|x\|}{\lambda_\max(A)}.
$$

Comment: Does this means that inequality `(3.9)` in the attached image is not correct? Could you please elaborate a little more?

Comment: If $\lambda_{\min}$ is considered instead, then $\frac{1}{2c}\leq \frac{1}{c} = \frac{\lVert x\rVert}{\lambda_{\min}(A)}$, which is what appears to be the correct version.

Comment: Yes it is $\lambda_{min}$!! My mistake. I did the appropriate changes in the post. So can we state that $$\|(A+cI)^{-1}\| = \frac{1}{\lambda_{min}(A+cI)} \leq \frac{1}{\lambda_{min}(A)+ c\lambda_{min}(I)} \leq \frac{1}{\lambda_{min}(A)}$$ to follow the proof?

Answer (score 1):

Write $$(A+cI)y=x$$ What you wish to show is
$$
\| y \| \leq \frac{1}{\lambda_{min}(A)}\| x\|.
$$
Let us show a little bit more, namely;
$$
\| y \| \leq \frac{1}{\lambda_{min}(A)+c}\| x\|.
$$
By definition of positive definiteness, $$ Ay \cdot y \geq \lambda_\min(A) \| y \|^2 $$
And of course, $A+cI_d$ is also positive definite, and
$$ Ay \cdot y \geq \left(\lambda_\min(A)+c \right)\| y \|^2 $$.

By Cauchy-Schwarz
$$
\| y \| \| x \| \geq x \cdot y 
$$
So
$$
\| y \| \| x \| \geq x \cdot y = Ay \cdot y \geq \left(\lambda_\min(A)+c \right)\| y \|^2 
$$
If $x=0$, then $y=0$, and the result is trivial. If not, then $y\neq0$, and we obtain the result by simplifying by $\|y\|$.